ScrollView en React-Native
Estoy creando un proyecto en React-Native, pero estoy teniendo un problema con una etiqueta,
cuando quiero implementar el ScrollView, directamente en el emulador no hace Scroll.
return (
<View style={styles.contenedor}>
  <ScrollView>
    <View style={styles.header}>
      <Header />

      {isValidPresupuesto ? (
        <ControlPresupuesto presupuesto={presupuesto} gastos={gastos} />
      ) : (
        <NuevoPresupuesto
          presupuesto={presupuesto}
          setPresupuesto={setPresupuesto}
          handleNuevoPresupuesto={handleNuevoPresupuesto}
        />
      )}
    </View>

    {isValidPresupuesto && <ListadoGastos gastos={gastos} />}
  </ScrollView>

Este es el código donde tengo insertada la etiqueta

¡Buenas! ¿Podría compartir el código del componente completo, incluyendo los estilos?
